# installing dependencies in ts

Tags: hardhat, typescript

when installing dependencies in a ts project ( npm install ) i get this error : " Cannot read properties of null (reading 'pickAlgorithm') "
the package :

```
{
```

"name": "flash-bot",
"version": "1.0.0",
"main": "index.js",
"license": "MIT",
"scripts": {
"prettier": "prettier --write 'contracts/**/*.sol'",
"bot": "hardhat run --network bsc bot/index.ts"
},
"devDependencies": {
"@nomiclabs/hardhat-ethers": "^2.0.0",
"@nomiclabs/hardhat-waffle": "^2.0.0",
"@typechain/ethers-v5": "^6.0.5",
"@typechain/hardhat": "^1.0.1",
"@types/chai": "^4.2.16",
"@types/mocha": "^8.2.2",
"@types/node": "^14.14.37",
"chai": "^4.3.4",
"ethereum-waffle": "^3.0.0",
"ethers": "^5.0.0",
"hardhat": "^2.1.2",
"prettier": "^2.2.1",
"prettier-plugin-solidity": "^1.0.0-beta.7",
"ts-generator": "^0.1.1",
"ts-node": "^9.1.1",
"typechain": "^4.0.3",
"typescript": "^4.2.4"
},